# assigning letters instead of numbers in a foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array like so.

```
$ARR_MSDS=array(
'K' => "Latex Warning: Caution this product contains natural rubber latex, which may cause allergic reactions!",
'L' => "Additional Shipping Charges: Please note that standard shipping costs do not apply.  This item requires an oversized and/or overweight shipping surcharge. Total shipping charges will be calculated upon receipt of order and you will be called with exact total.",
'M' => "Bariatric Rated: Please note that this product has a Bariatric rating." ,
'B' => "HazMat: Non-returnable.  This item is classified as a hazardous material by DOT and has the following shipping restrictions: ground shipping only (no air shipments) and only ship to the 48 continuous states.  Additional shipping charges may apply.",
'P' => "Refrigerated Item: Shipped on ice only Monday - Wednesday.",
'E' => "Prescription Drug or Device: This item may only be sold to a licensed healthcare facility.",
'A' => "Special Order: This item is a special order and is non-returnable.  Please ensure this is the item you want.  If you have any questions, please contact us.  It may be drop shipped from the manufacturer.",
'X' => "Earth-Friendly: This item is certified Earth-Friendly.",
'V' => "Controlled Drug: Requires a DEA license and may only be shipped to the address on the license.",
10  => "Class II Drug:  Non-refundable.  This drug requires an original DEA Form 222 to be in our hands prior to shipping your order.  Please contact us if you require assistance.",
'T' => "No Return: Cannot be sent back.",
'C' => "Short-Dated Item: This item has a shorter shelf life, usually less than 6 months, and is priced accordingly.  This item is non-returnable."
```

);

My clients decided to use letters instead of numbers in the database. When I use a foreach to execute what needs to happen they are using numbers and not the corresponding letters.

Here is my foreach.

```
foreach($ARR_MSDS as $k=>$v){
    $imgPArry  = explode(":",$v);
    $imgPath   = $imgPArry[0];
    $imgTile =  "<span ><strong>".$imgPArry[0]."</strong>";
    $imgTile1 = $imgPArry[1];
    if($imgPArry[2]!='')
    {
        $tileMain = $imgTile ." :".$imgTile1." ".$imgPArry[2]."</span>";
    }else{
        $tileMain = $imgTile ." :".$imgTile1."</span>";
    }
    if(is_array($MSDS_LIST)){
        //onmouseover=\"Tip('<strong>Please call customer service at 1(800) 748-5665 to order item</strong>', BALLOON, true, ABOVE, true, OFFSETX, -17)\"
        $MSDS_LIST_RESULT.=(in_array($k,$MSDS_LIST))?"<img src='/images/msdx/$imgPath.gif' onmouseout=\"hideDiv()\" onmouseover=\"showDiv('$tileMain')\"   style='padding:2px;margin:0px;'>":"";
    }
    else{
        $MSDS_LIST_RESULT=($k==$MSDS_LIST)?"<img src='/images/msdx/$imgPath.gif'   title='$v' style='padding:2px;'>":"";
    }
    }
```

The $MSDS_LIST is an array that looks like this.

Array ( [0] => R )

Comment: What's the question?  You can have associative arrays in PHP with alphanumeric keys such as in your original example.  When you foreach over it as in `foreach($ARR_MSDS as $k=>$v){`, $k should be the key, and $v should be the value.  Try doing `print_r` on your array and make sure it has the keys you're expecting it to have.

Comment: Yes, there's no question here :/

Comment: I see a `10` in the keys that has been slipped into the list surreptitiously... is this the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're confusing the numbers in the `$imgPArry` variable for those of your master array. The numbers you see being reference on the `$imgPArry` are because of the `explode` happening to a single value from your master array. In other words, the `foreach`is working properly with the letters.

During each iteration of the `foreach`, an `explode` is happening to the value, breaking it at the `:`. This new subarray then has several parts, depending on how many `:` were in the value. Those are referenced by numbers.

For example,

```
"Latex Warning: Caution this product contains natural rubber latex, which may cause allergic reactions!"
```

...becomes...

```
$imgPArry[0] = "Latex Warning";
$imgPArry[1] = " Caution this product contains natural rubber latex, which may cause allergic reactions!";
```

Does that answer your question?